# Mongodb Searching sharding key is very slow

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, sharding, bitnami

I set up a mongodb with 3 shards by using bitnami's chart: [mongodb-sharded](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/mongodb-sharded)
 and I got two problems.

My sharding collection has more than 38 millions records.

The first problem is some mongodb pods take a lot of memory, more than 10G from the whole memory of 32G in a node.  I found some similar issues from stackoverflow and I would try to tackle this problem.

The other problem is: when I do a search which matches the sharding key, it's very slow and sometimes it will be time out.

Here is my collection's indexes:

```
ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard-0:PRIMARY> db.LogInfo.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "collation" : {
            "locale" : "en_US",
            "caseLevel" : false,
            "caseFirst" : "off",
            "strength" : 2,
            "numericOrdering" : false,
            "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
            "maxVariable" : "punct",
            "normalization" : false,
            "backwards" : false,
            "version" : "57.1"
        }
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "Properties.Time" : 1
        },
        "name" : "Properties.Time_1",
        "collation" : {
            "locale" : "en_US",
            "caseLevel" : false,
            "caseFirst" : "off",
            "strength" : 2,
            "numericOrdering" : false,
            "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
            "maxVariable" : "punct",
            "normalization" : false,
            "backwards" : false,
            "version" : "57.1"
        }
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "Properties.Plot" : 1,
            "Properties.Time" : 1
        },
        "name" : "Properties.Plot_1_Properties.Time_1",
        "collation" : {
            "locale" : "en_US",
            "caseLevel" : false,
            "caseFirst" : "off",
            "strength" : 2,
            "numericOrdering" : false,
            "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
            "maxVariable" : "punct",
            "normalization" : false,
            "backwards" : false,
            "version" : "57.1"
        }
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "Properties.Scenario" : 1,
            "Properties.Time" : 1
        },
        "name" : "Properties.Scenario_1_Properties.Time_1",
        "collation" : {
            "locale" : "en_US",
            "caseLevel" : false,
            "caseFirst" : "off",
            "strength" : 2,
            "numericOrdering" : false,
            "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
            "maxVariable" : "punct",
            "normalization" : false,
            "backwards" : false,
            "version" : "57.1"
        }
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "Properties.SecsFunction" : 1,
            "Properties.Time" : 1
        },
        "name" : "Properties.SecsFunction_1_Properties.Time_1",
        "collation" : {
            "locale" : "en_US",
            "caseLevel" : false,
            "caseFirst" : "off",
            "strength" : 2,
            "numericOrdering" : false,
            "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
            "maxVariable" : "punct",
            "normalization" : false,
            "backwards" : false,
            "version" : "57.1"
        }
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "Properties.EapId" : "hashed",
            "Properties.Time" : 1
        },
        "name" : "Properties.EapId_hashed_Properties.Time_1"
    }
]
```

The key "Properties.EapId_hashed_Properties.Time_1" is the sharding key.

If I search

```js
db.LogInfo.find({"Properties.SecsFunction": "s6f11", "Properties.Time": {$gte: ISODate("2021-03-10")}})
```

This search matches an index and it will search all the 3 shards. It's very fast within 0.01 seconds.

But if I search

```js
db.LogInfo.find(
    {
        "Properties.EapId": "12eap012",
        "Properties.Time": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2021-03-17")
        }
    }
)
```

which should use the sharding key, I think, it's very flow.  Sometimes it will take more than 5 seconds and sometimes it will be time out.  I've checked the indexes several times but I can't figure out why.

Please advise.  Thanks.

update: Mongodb version: 4.4.3

update: shards are built as replica set = 3.

update: below is the query plan for the problematic search. (I drop the executionStat() due to stackoverflow's 30000 characters limit.)

```js
{ 
    "queryPlanner" : { 
        "mongosPlannerVersion" : NumberInt(1), 
        "winningPlan" : { 
            "stage" : "SHARD_MERGE", 
            "shards" : [
                { 
                    "shardName" : "ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard-1", 
                    "connectionString" : "ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard-1/ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard1-data-0.ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-headless.ice-system.svc.cluster.local:27017,ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard1-data-1.ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-headless.ice-system.svc.cluster.local:27017,ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard1-data-2.ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-headless.ice-system.svc.cluster.local:27017", 
                    "serverInfo" : { 
                        "host" : "ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard1-data-1", 
                        "port" : NumberInt(27017), 
                        "version" : "4.4.3", 
                        "gitVersion" : "913d6b62acfbb344dde1b116f4161360acd8fd13"
                    }, 
                    "plannerVersion" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "namespace" : "LogCenter.LogInfo", 
                    "indexFilterSet" : false, 
                    "parsedQuery" : { 
                        "$and" : [
                            { 
                                "Properties.EapId" : { 
                                    "$eq" : "12eap012"
                                }
                            }, 
                            { 
                                "Properties.Time" : { 
                                    "$gte" : ISODate("2021-03-17T00:00:00.000+0000")
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "collation" : { 
                        "locale" : "en_US", 
                        "caseLevel" : false, 
                        "caseFirst" : "off", 
                        "strength" : NumberInt(2), 
                        "numericOrdering" : false, 
                        "alternate" : "non-ignorable", 
                        "maxVariable" : "punct", 
                        "normalization" : false, 
                        "backwards" : false, 
                        "version" : "57.1"
                    }, 
                    "winningPlan" : { 
                        "stage" : "SHARDING_FILTER", 
                        "inputStage" : { 
                            "stage" : "FETCH", 
                            "filter" : { 
                                "Properties.EapId" : { 
                                    "$eq" : "12eap012"
                                }
                            }, 
                            "inputStage" : { 
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                                "keyPattern" : { 
                                    "Properties.Time" : 1.0
                                }, 
                                "indexName" : "Properties.Time_1", 
                                "collation" : { 
                                    "locale" : "en_US", 
                                    "caseLevel" : false, 
                                    "caseFirst" : "off", 
                                    "strength" : NumberInt(2), 
                                    "numericOrdering" : false, 
                                    "alternate" : "non-ignorable", 
                                    "maxVariable" : "punct", 
                                    "normalization" : false, 
                                    "backwards" : false, 
                                    "version" : "57.1"
                                }, 
                                "isMultiKey" : false, 
                                "multiKeyPaths" : { 
                                    "Properties.Time" : [

                                    ]
                                }, 
                                "isUnique" : false, 
                                "isSparse" : false, 
                                "isPartial" : false, 
                                "indexVersion" : NumberInt(2), 
                                "direction" : "forward", 
                                "indexBounds" : { 
                                    "Properties.Time" : [
                                        "[new Date(1615939200000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    "rejectedPlans" : [

                    ]
                }, 
                { 
                    "shardName" : "ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard-0", 
                    "connectionString" : "ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard-0/ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard0-data-0.ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-headless.ice-system.svc.cluster.local:27017,ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard0-data-1.ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-headless.ice-system.svc.cluster.local:27017,ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard0-data-2.ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-headless.ice-system.svc.cluster.local:27017", 
                    "serverInfo" : { 
                        "host" : "ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard0-data-0", 
                        "port" : NumberInt(27017), 
                        "version" : "4.4.3", 
                        "gitVersion" : "913d6b62acfbb344dde1b116f4161360acd8fd13"
                    }, 
                    "plannerVersion" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "namespace" : "LogCenter.LogInfo", 
                    "indexFilterSet" : false, 
                    "parsedQuery" : { 
                        "$and" : [
                            { 
                                "Properties.EapId" : { 
                                    "$eq" : "12eap012"
                                }
                            }, 
                            { 
                                "Properties.Time" : { 
                                    "$gte" : ISODate("2021-03-17T00:00:00.000+0000")
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "collation" : { 
                        "locale" : "en_US", 
                        "caseLevel" : false, 
                        "caseFirst" : "off", 
                        "strength" : NumberInt(2), 
                        "numericOrdering" : false, 
                        "alternate" : "non-ignorable", 
                        "maxVariable" : "punct", 
                        "normalization" : false, 
                        "backwards" : false, 
                        "version" : "57.1"
                    }, 
                    "winningPlan" : { 
                        "stage" : "SHARDING_FILTER", 
                        "inputStage" : { 
                            "stage" : "FETCH", 
                            "filter" : { 
                                "Properties.EapId" : { 
                                    "$eq" : "12eap012"
                                }
                            }, 
                            "inputStage" : { 
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                                "keyPattern" : { 
                                    "Properties.Time" : 1.0
                                }, 
                                "indexName" : "Properties.Time_1", 
                                "collation" : { 
                                    "locale" : "en_US", 
                                    "caseLevel" : false, 
                                    "caseFirst" : "off", 
                                    "strength" : NumberInt(2), 
                                    "numericOrdering" : false, 
                                    "alternate" : "non-ignorable", 
                                    "maxVariable" : "punct", 
                                    "normalization" : false, 
                                    "backwards" : false, 
                                    "version" : "57.1"
                                }, 
                                "isMultiKey" : false, 
                                "multiKeyPaths" : { 
                                    "Properties.Time" : [

                                    ]
                                }, 
                                "isUnique" : false, 
                                "isSparse" : false, 
                                "isPartial" : false, 
                                "indexVersion" : NumberInt(2), 
                                "direction" : "forward", 
                                "indexBounds" : { 
                                    "Properties.Time" : [
                                        "[new Date(1615939200000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    "rejectedPlans" : [

                    ]
                }, 
                { 
                    "shardName" : "ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard-2", 
                    "connectionString" : "ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard-2/ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard2-data-0.ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-headless.ice-system.svc.cluster.local:27017,ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard2-data-1.ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-headless.ice-system.svc.cluster.local:27017,ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard2-data-2.ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-headless.ice-system.svc.cluster.local:27017", 
                    "serverInfo" : { 
                        "host" : "ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-shard2-data-0", 
                        "port" : NumberInt(27017), 
                        "version" : "4.4.3", 
                        "gitVersion" : "913d6b62acfbb344dde1b116f4161360acd8fd13"
                    }, 
                    "plannerVersion" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "namespace" : "LogCenter.LogInfo", 
                    "indexFilterSet" : false, 
                    "parsedQuery" : { 
                        "$and" : [
                            { 
                                "Properties.EapId" : { 
                                    "$eq" : "12eap012"
                                }
                            }, 
                            { 
                                "Properties.Time" : { 
                                    "$gte" : ISODate("2021-03-17T00:00:00.000+0000")
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "collation" : { 
                        "locale" : "en_US", 
                        "caseLevel" : false, 
                        "caseFirst" : "off", 
                        "strength" : NumberInt(2), 
                        "numericOrdering" : false, 
                        "alternate" : "non-ignorable", 
                        "maxVariable" : "punct", 
                        "normalization" : false, 
                        "backwards" : false, 
                        "version" : "57.1"
                    }, 
                    "winningPlan" : { 
                        "stage" : "SHARDING_FILTER", 
                        "inputStage" : { 
                            "stage" : "FETCH", 
                            "filter" : { 
                                "Properties.EapId" : { 
                                    "$eq" : "12eap012"
                                }
                            }, 
                            "inputStage" : { 
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                                "keyPattern" : { 
                                    "Properties.Time" : 1.0
                                }, 
                                "indexName" : "Properties.Time_1", 
                                "collation" : { 
                                    "locale" : "en_US", 
                                    "caseLevel" : false, 
                                    "caseFirst" : "off", 
                                    "strength" : NumberInt(2), 
                                    "numericOrdering" : false, 
                                    "alternate" : "non-ignorable", 
                                    "maxVariable" : "punct", 
                                    "normalization" : false, 
                                    "backwards" : false, 
                                    "version" : "57.1"
                                }, 
                                "isMultiKey" : false, 
                                "multiKeyPaths" : { 
                                    "Properties.Time" : [

                                    ]
                                }, 
                                "isUnique" : false, 
                                "isSparse" : false, 
                                "isPartial" : false, 
                                "indexVersion" : NumberInt(2), 
                                "direction" : "forward", 
                                "indexBounds" : { 
                                    "Properties.Time" : [
                                        "[new Date(1615939200000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    "rejectedPlans" : [

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }, 
    "serverInfo" : { 
        "host" : "ice-shard-mongodb-sharded-mongos-59576fb8b8-n47n5", 
        "port" : NumberInt(27017), 
        "version" : "4.4.3", 
        "gitVersion" : "913d6b62acfbb344dde1b116f4161360acd8fd13"
    }, 
    "ok" : 1.0, 
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1616372015, 12), 
    "$clusterTime" : { 
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1616372015, 14), 
        "signature" : { 
            "hash" : BinData(0, "vVxiZGic6un9QIInadoHCfBCX2Y="), 
            "keyId" : NumberLong(6924833040434724866)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://p-mongo.github.io/mongodb-faq/query/indexing-query-optimization/#query-plan

Comment: Check the explain output for the query.  Edit it into the question if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for @D.SM and Joe, I put the explain result in my post.  The result is too large to comply with stackoverflow's characters limit so I drop the executionStat() result.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.shardCollection/#:~:text=If%20the%20collection%20has%20a,support%20the%20shard%20key%20pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause why my search didn't use the sharding key.  It's all about the collation.

Sharding key always use `collation : { locale : "simple" }` to do a binary comparison, while in my case my collection and indexes are designed to use `"collation" : { "locale" : "en_US", "strength" : 2 }`.

After redesigning my collection without any collation, now everything is fine.