# mongodb fallocate not supported might bring about linux's crash

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, nfs

I deployed a sharding mongodb on kubernetes with sharding=3, replicaset=3, mongos=2 using bitnami's helm chart (mongodb-sharded v3.4.4). Every few days one of the linux machine that mongodb node run on crash.

After observing several possible metrics I found that before linux crashed and restarted there were a lot of mongodb threads (more than 1000 threads) eating up the machine's memory (I observed this by viewing grafana and linux's htop). At the same time the kubernetes didn't count these memory usage so I thought these threads might become zombie processes.

Mongodb's logs only show these kind of errors like this (9 mongodb nodes say the same thing.):

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-10T09:08:48.798+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":95,"message":"[1618045728:798324][1:0x7f9fbf72f140], connection: __posix_std_fallocate, 58: /bitnami/mongodb/data/db/journal/WiredTigerTmplog.0000000001: fallocate:: Operation not supported"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-10T09:08:48.798+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":95,"message":"[1618045728:798373][1:0x7f9fbf72f140], connection: __posix_sys_fallocate, 75: /bitnami/mongodb/data/db/journal/WiredTigerTmplog.0000000001: fallocate:: Operation not supported"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-10T09:08:50.968+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":95,"message":"[1618045730:968947][1:0x7f9fbc727700], log-server: __posix_std_fallocate, 58: /bitnami/mongodb/data/db/journal/WiredTigerTmplog.0000000002: fallocate:: Operation not supported"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-10T09:08:50.969+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":95,"message":"[1618045730:968998][1:0x7f9fbc727700], log-server: __posix_sys_fallocate, 75: /bitnami/mongodb/data/db/journal/WiredTigerTmplog.0000000002: fallocate:: Operation not supported"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-10T09:08:51.938+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":95,"message":"[1618045731:938978][1:0x7f9fbc727700], log-server: __posix_std_fallocate, 58: /bitnami/mongodb/data/db/journal/WiredTigerTmplog.0000000003: fallocate:: Operation not supported"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-10T09:08:51.939+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":95,"message":"[1618045731:939010][1:0x7f9fbc727700], log-server: __posix_sys_fallocate, 75: /bitnami/mongodb/data/db/journal/WiredTigerTmplog.0000000003: fallocate:: Operation not supported"}}
```

Mongodb's log also say these warning:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-10T09:08:48.249+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-10T09:08:48.282+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20720,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Available memory is less than system memory","attr":{"availableMemSizeMB":8192,"systemMemSizeMB":48296}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-10T09:08:52.001+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":22668,   "ctx":"replSetDistLockPinger","msg":"Pinging failed for distributed lock pinger","attr":{"error":{"code":129,"codeName":"LockStateChangeFailed","errmsg":"findAndModify query predicate didn't match any lock document"}}}
```

So I think 'fallocate not supported' bring about the crash of linux.

Below is my environment settings:

- Kubernetes: 1.19.6
- worker node linux: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (all worker nodes apply the same version.)
- Mongo sharding chart: [mongodb-sharded v3.4.4](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/mongodb-sharded/3.4.4)
- mongodb version: 4.4.4
- NFS: synology RS1221+, DSM 6.2.3, NFS version 4.1 (I use this to provide pv for mongodb.)

Comment: make sure, you are queries on shard key only.

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA Sure it is. I just adjusted my collection design and the query performance is very good among 40m records. see my other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66729435/mongodb-searching-sharding-key-is-very-slow/66947788#66947788

Comment: have a look on below link and see if it helps

https://forums.percona.com/t/wiredtiger-error-error-95-fallocate-operation-not-supported/7988/2

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA  I saw this post before, but there is no solution.  I tried the command 'fallocate -l 10M 10meg' in one of the mongodb container.  If I run this command in /var/tmp it succeeds.  If I run this command in /bitnami/mongodb/data/db, where is the db folder and mounted as a PV (in an NFS built by Synology), it says "fallocate: fallocate failed: Operation not supported".  Yes, I know that NFS v4.1 doesn't support the command fallocate.  I just want to know if there exists any feasible solution.

Comment: @ArtTsai did you find a solution to this? we are facing a similar issue.

Comment: Hi @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar, Yes, we solved this problem.  We changed from NFS to iSCSI. Hope this helps.