# Try to use iSCSI volume in Kubernetes Cluster but got "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program"

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, iscsi

Due to problems might caused by NFS [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67051493/mongodb-fallocate-not-supported-might-bring-about-linuxs-crash), I tried to build iSCSI volume mount in K8S cluster, yet I got errors:

> MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "iscsipd-rw" : mount failed: exit status 32
>
> Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/iscsi/iface-default/192.168.20.100:3260-iqn.2020-09.com.xxxx:yyyy.testtarget-lun-1 --scope -- mount -t ext4 -o defaults /dev/disk/by-path/ip-192.168.20.100:3260-iscsi-iqn.2020-09.com.xxxx:yyyy.testtarget-lun-1 /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/iscsi/iface-default/192.168.20.100:3260-iqn.2020-09.com.xxxx:yyyy.testtarget-lun-1
>
> mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/iscsi/iface-default/192.168.20.100:3260-iqn.2020-09.com.xxxx:yyyy.testtarget-lun-1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

At beginning I follow [this document](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/volumes/iscsi#prerequisites) to create iSCSI initiator, due to errors caused by different situation, I've tried various settings multiple times.
iSCSI initiator connection looked well

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 1 GiB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2CDE61DE-F57A-4C0B-AFB6-9DD7040A8BBD

Tue Apr 13 15:41:57 i@kt04:~$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0   64G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
├─sda3                      8:3    0   49G  0 part
│ └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   63G  0 lvm  /
└─sda4                      8:4    0   14G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   63G  0 lvm  /
sdb                         8:16   0    1G  0 disk
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom

Tue Apr 13 15:45:33 i@kt04:~$ sudo ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 13 15:41 ip-192.168.20.100:3260-iscsi-iqn.2020-09.com.xxxx:yyyy.testtarget-lun-1 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 13 11:07 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 13 11:07 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 13 11:07 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 13 11:07 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 13 11:07 pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 13 01:55 pci-0000:02:01.0-ata-1 -> ../../sr0

Tue Apr 13 15:46:18 i@kt04:~$ sudo iscsiadm -m session -P 3
iSCSI Transport Class version 2.0-870
version 2.0-874
Target: iqn.2020-09.com.xxxx:yyyy.testtarget (non-flash)
        Current Portal: 192.168.20.100:3260,1
        Persistent Portal: 192.168.20.100:3260,1
                **********
                Interface:
                **********
                Iface Name: default
                Iface Transport: tcp
                Iface Initiatorname: iqn.2020-09.com.xxxx:yyyy.testtarget
                Iface IPaddress: 192.168.30.24
                Iface HWaddress: <empty>
                Iface Netdev: <empty>
                SID: 2
                iSCSI Connection State: LOGGED IN
                iSCSI Session State: LOGGED_IN
                Internal iscsid Session State: NO CHANGE
                *********
                Timeouts:
                *********
                Recovery Timeout: 120
                Target Reset Timeout: 30
                LUN Reset Timeout: 30
                Abort Timeout: 15
                *****
                CHAP:
                *****
                username: <empty>
                password: ********
                username_in: <empty>
                password_in: ********
                ************************
                Negotiated iSCSI params:
                ************************
                HeaderDigest: None
                DataDigest: None
                MaxRecvDataSegmentLength: 262144
                MaxXmitDataSegmentLength: 262144
                FirstBurstLength: 65536
                MaxBurstLength: 262144
                ImmediateData: Yes
                InitialR2T: Yes
                MaxOutstandingR2T: 1
                ************************
                Attached SCSI devices:
                ************************
                Host Number: 33 State: running
                scsi33 Channel 00 Id 0 Lun: 1
                        Attached scsi disk sdb          State: running

Tue Apr 13 15:57:55 i@kt04:~$ sudo systemctl status open-iscsi
● open-iscsi.service - Login to default iSCSI targets
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/open-iscsi.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2021-04-13 11:03:20 CST; 5h 6min ago
     Docs: man:iscsiadm(8)
           man:iscsid(8)
  Process: 1352 ExecStop=/lib/open-iscsi/logout-all.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1351 ExecStop=/bin/sync (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1301 ExecStop=/lib/open-iscsi/umountiscsi.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1416 ExecStart=/lib/open-iscsi/activate-storage.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1383 ExecStart=/sbin/iscsiadm -m node --loginall=automatic (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1416 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 13 11:03:20 kt04 systemd[1]: Starting Login to default iSCSI targets...
Apr 13 11:03:20 kt04 iscsiadm[1383]: Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.2020-09.com.xxxx:yyyy.testtarget, portal: 192.168.20.100,3260] (multiple)
Apr 13 11:03:20 kt04 iscsiadm[1383]: Login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2020-09.com.xxxx:yyyy.testtarget, portal: 192.168.20.100,3260] successful.
Apr 13 11:03:20 kt04 systemd[1]: Started Login to default iSCSI targets.

Tue Apr 13 16:09:28 i@kt04:~$ sudo systemctl status iscsid
● iscsid.service - iSCSI initiator daemon (iscsid)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/iscsid.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-04-13 11:03:20 CST; 5h 6min ago
     Docs: man:iscsid(8)
  Process: 1374 ExecStart=/sbin/iscsid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1364 ExecStartPre=/lib/open-iscsi/startup-checks.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1377 (iscsid)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/iscsid.service
           ├─1376 /sbin/iscsid
           └─1377 /sbin/iscsid

Apr 13 11:03:20 kt04 systemd[1]: Starting iSCSI initiator daemon (iscsid)...
Apr 13 11:03:20 kt04 iscsid[1374]: iSCSI logger with pid=1376 started!
Apr 13 11:03:20 kt04 systemd[1]: Started iSCSI initiator daemon (iscsid).
Apr 13 11:03:21 kt04 iscsid[1376]: iSCSI daemon with pid=1377 started!
Apr 13 11:03:21 kt04 iscsid[1376]: Connection2:0 to [target: iqn.2020-09.com.xxxx:yyyy.testtarget, portal: 192.168.20.100,3260] through [iface: default] is operational now

Tue Apr 13 16:21:21 i@kt04:~$ cat /proc/scsi/scsi
Attached devices:
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: NECVMWar Model: VMware SATA CD00 Rev: 1.00
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi32 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: VMware   Model: Virtual disk     Rev: 2.0
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 06
Host: scsi33 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 01
  Vendor: SYNOLOGY Model: iSCSI Storage    Rev: 4.0
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
```

I've tried "sdb" worked as raw disk like showed above, and also created a sdb1 partition mounted with ext4 filesystem another time (even created LVM once) which caused "mount failed: exit status 32 /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy" error

pod yaml I used

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: iscsipd
spec:
  nodeName: kt04
  containers:
  - name: iscsipd-rw
    image: kubernetes/pause
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/mnt/iscsipd"
      name: iscsipd-rw
  restartPolicy: Always
  volumes:
  - name: iscsipd-rw
    iscsi:
      targetPortal: 192.168.20.100:3260
      iqn: iqn.2020-09.com.xxxx:yyyy.testtarget
      lun: 1
      fsType: ext4
      readOnly: false
```

The last try I use fdisk to create a sdb1 partition with ext4 but not mounted to /mnt which result as below, still got the same error "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program"

```
Wed Apr 14 11:25:06 ice@kt04:~$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0   64G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
├─sda3                      8:3    0   49G  0 part
│ └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   63G  0 lvm  /
└─sda4                      8:4    0   14G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   63G  0 lvm  /
sdb                         8:16   0    1G  0 disk
└─sdb1                      8:17   0 1023M  0 part
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

At NAS(use Synology RS1221) iSCSI configuration panel, it shows that Target is connected (Lun is Thick Provisioning)

k8s on bare-metal version: 1.19.6

iscsiadm version 2.0-874

open-iscsi version 2.0.874-5ubuntu2.10

Anyone can provide some suggestion that what I can try to make it work, or point out what I did wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

problem solved. thanks to [Long Wu Yuan] on Slack#kubernetes-users.

information provided before problem solved:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              1.6G  3.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   62G   10G   49G  18% /
tmpfs                              7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  146M  764M  16% /boot

$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0   64G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
├─sda3                      8:3    0   49G  0 part
│ └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   63G  0 lvm  /
└─sda4                      8:4    0   14G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   63G  0 lvm  /
sdb                         8:16   0    1G  0 disk
└─sdb1                      8:17   0 1023M  0 part
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

delete pod then

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              1.6G  3.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   62G   10G   49G  18% /
tmpfs                              7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  146M  764M  16% /boot
```

execute `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=512 status=progress` then

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=512 status=progress
512+0 records in
512+0 records out
536870912 bytes (537 MB, 512 MiB) copied, 4.85588 s, 111 MB/s
$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0   64G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
├─sda3                      8:3    0   49G  0 part
│ └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   63G  0 lvm  /
└─sda4                      8:4    0   14G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   63G  0 lvm  /
sdb                         8:16   0    1G  0 disk
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

then apply pod again, it WORKS！, df -h & lsblk information after pod working

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              1.6G  3.7M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   62G   10G   49G  17% /
tmpfs                              7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  146M  764M  16% /boot

$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0   64G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
├─sda3                      8:3    0   49G  0 part
│ └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   63G  0 lvm  /
└─sda4                      8:4    0   14G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   63G  0 lvm  /
sdb                         8:16   0    1G  0 disk
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

As Long said, I should know better about the error message "bad superblock" and find solution or what the mis-configuration of my environment is for this iSCSI volume situation.